# How to auto adjust an image and its corresponding text in a div

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display a image in a div section. Here is the css i am using

```
    #imagesection {margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; float:left; border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;}
    #container {width:90%; margin:3% 0px 0px 10%;}
    #full_page {height:auto; width:auto;}
    #name {background-color:#FFF; word-wrap:break-word; word-break:}
    </style>
```

The image is being displayed well but when i added text **($name)** It's loosing the style. Please check the image below [image]

```
<div id="full_page">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="Gallery">
                <div id="imagesection">
                    <img src = <?php echo  $picture;?> />
                                    <div id="name">
                    <?php echo $name; ?>
                </div>
                </div>


             </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to be continued in new line if length of image is exceeded.
I mean the text should be automatically adjusted with correspondence to image inside div, With out leaving blank spaces.
Please suggest me what should be done to achieve this...

**Updated Snapshot :**
[image]

Comment: Set `width` and `height` attribute too (  `<img height="500px" width="250px" src = <?php echo  $picture;?> />` )...

Comment: i hope this is  not just spam ad for windows 8 :-)

Comment: Please don't mind, I am trying to fetch json data from facebook api and display it on html. Just as an Image gallery with my posts. So i just showed you a sample image where i am unable to code css. @Dagon

Comment: @softgenic No I cannot specify height and width. If i do so the image looses it's quality. I mean The size of images vary from small to big. It depends on image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Float on your image tag

For example:

```
css
{

#image
{
float: left;
}

}

<img id="image" src = <?php echo  $picture;?> />
```

**Update:**
After watching your updated screenshot. What I sugggest you can do is to get the width of the image and then pass that to your div that will automatically stops the text to overflow the div

Here is the code of getting height and width

```
<?php

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");

echo "Image width " .$width;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image height " .$height;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image type " .$type;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Attribute " .$attr;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @soft genic But please check the css code i have copied into my question I already added #imagesection {margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; float:left; border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;}

Comment: Ya i got this idea. But dint tried.
And finally you gave the best answer. Thanks for your kind support

Answer (score 0):

Always set your img width, height, border and alt tags. I would also set the width of the image div and the text div explicitly. If you set all three of them to 500px for instance, the text should wrap.

Comment: What if the image has more than 500px ? or In case if it is simply a thumbnail etc(Tiny images) ?